# Проблема с получением значения в элементе WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть метод авторизации:

```
public static int Auth(string username, string password)
{
    var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
    };
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = client.PostAsync(baseAdress + "Token", content).Result;
        access_token = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return Convert.ToInt32(response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

При вызове я должен ввести аргументы, они у меня берутся из texbox`ов:

```
if (Command.Auth(Username.Text, Password.Text) == 200)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Авторизация выполнена!");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(Command.access_token);
}
```

Проблема в том, что авторизация не проходит, а дело в том, что элементы wpf, как-то неправильно передают значения, потому что тот же метод в Windows Forms работает. Да и в WPF частично тоже работает, но если только я введу значения в ручную, вот так:

```
if (Command.Auth("test123@mail.ru", "1234567890qwertY-") == 200)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Авторизация выполнена!");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(Command.access_token);
}
```

Помогите решить проблему

Comment: Магия, не иначе. Берите Fiddler и смотрите что реально отпавляется

Comment: Покажите ваш UI, дайте воспроизводимый пример. Без него это какой-то подземный стук покамест.

Comment: а как у вас биндится пароль в текстбокс? Возможно он просто не передаётся